# Why should I prefer `Option::ok_or_else` instead of `Option::ok_or`?

Tags: rust

I just saw the following change in a pull request:

```
- .ok_or(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Decode error"));
+ .ok_or_else(|| Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Decode error"));
```

The only differences I know are:

1. In `ok_or` we have already created `Error` by `Error::new` and passed it into a adaptor.
2. In `ok_or_else` we have passed a closure which will produce such a value but it may not be called if there is `Some` data in the `Option`.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The primary reason to use `ok_or_else` or *any* of the `..._or_else` methods is to avoid executing a function when it's not needed. In the case of `Option::ok_or_else` or `Option::unwrap_or_else`, there's no need to run extra code when the `Option` is `Some`. This can make code faster, depending on what happens in the error case

In this example, `Error::new` likely performs allocation, but it could also write to standard out, make a network request, or anything any piece of Rust code can do; it's hard to tell from the outside. It's generally safer to place such code in a closure so you don't have to worry about extraneous side effects when the success case happens.

Clippy lints this for you as well:

```
fn main() {
    let foo = None;
    foo.unwrap_or("hello".to_string());
}
```

```
warning: use of `unwrap_or` followed by a function call
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |     foo.unwrap_or("hello".to_string());
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: try this: `unwrap_or_else(|| "hello".to_string())`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(clippy::or_fun_call)]` on by default
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#or_fun_call
```

Comment: Okay, but could you also tell which cases are appropriate for `unwrap_or` and for `unwrap_or_else` and others? I understand that some cases are when you use them with scalars, for example, like `unwrap_or(0)` but that's all?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy or any case where you've *already* computed the function for whatever reason; it doesn't have to be a "simple" type like an integer.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to performance implications, more complex arguments in `ok_or` might yield unexpected results if one is not careful enough; consider the following case:

```
fn main() {
    let value: Option<usize> = Some(1);

    let result = value.ok_or({ println!("value is not Some!"); 0 }); // actually, it is

    assert_eq!(result, Ok(1)); // this holds, but "value is not Some!" was printed
}
```

This would have been avoided with `ok_or_else` (and the same goes for other `*_or_else` functions), because the closure is not evaluated if the variant is `Some`.

Comment: How does this differ from my "but it could also write to standard out" line?

Comment: @Shepmaster it places focus on a different thing - the initial shape of your answer sounded mostly performance-oriented and possible misleading results may not have been obvious to a skimming reader.

Answer (score 4):

The signature of `std::io::Error::new` is

```
fn new<E>(kind: ErrorKind, error: E) -> Error 
where
    E: Into<Box<Error + Send + Sync>>,
```

This means that `Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Decode error")` allocates memory on the heap because `error` needs to be converted into `Box<Error + Send + Sync>` to be of any use.

Consequently, this pull request removes unneeded memory allocation/deallocation when the `Result` value is `Result::Ok`.

Comment: Pedantically, it doesn't *require* that `into` is ever actually called, so there's no guarantee that allocation occurs. It's possible that there's some condition where allocation doesn't occur. However, it's indeed very likely.