# Option types and early returns. return an Error when is_none()

Tags: rust

Using match (like in `bar`) seems to be a common approach..

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MyErrors {
    SomeError,
}

fn foo(x: Option<u64>) -> Result<u64, MyErrors> {
    if x.is_none() {
      return Err(MyErrors::SomeError);
    } 

    // .. some long code where more options
    // are checked and matched 
    // The ok here is just so the code is simple and compiles
    Ok(x.unwrap() * 2)
}

fn bar(x: Option<u64>) -> Result<u64, MyErrors> {
    match x {
        None => {
            return Err(MyErrors::SomeError)?;
        }
        Some(v) => {
           // .. some long code where more options
           // are checked and matched 
           // The ok here is just so the code is simple and compiles
           Ok(x.unwrap() * 2)
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    foo(Some(1));
    bar(Some(2));
}
```

However, early returns (such as in `foo`) significantly reduce how nested the code looks like. If there are multiple times when an option has to be unwrapped or an error returned, code like bar gets very nested...

What is the recommended practice for early returning an error in the case of empty options?

Comment: If you're a fan of method chains, there's [ok_or](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or).

Comment: If you don't mind, I'd prefer if you waited a bit before accepting my answer. A better one can very well appear. But that's completely up to you, of course.

Comment: Ok, I just liked your answer very much :)

Comment: what wrong with `x.and_then(|x| Some(x * 2)).ok_or(MyErrors::SomeError)` ?

Comment: nothing, just that given that there is a lot of code coming after, I am actually looking for an early return approach. `ok_or_else`+`?` is ideal.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If a longer method chain is undesirable due to complex logic inside, there are still a few readable, low-indent options.

## `ok_or` and `?`

We can convert an `Option` to a `Result` with a desired error, and immediately unwrap it with the `?` operator. This solution probably provides the least indent possible, and can be easily used to "unwrap" multiple `Option`s.

```
fn bar1(x: Option<u64>) -> Result<u64, MyErrors> {
    let x = x.ok_or(MyErrors::SomeError)?;
    // A lot of stuff going on.
    Ok(x * 2)
}
```

This will evaluate the error inside `ok_or` regardless of whether or not it will actually be used. If this computation is expensive, `ok_or_else`, which produces the error lazily, will be more efficient ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547293/why-should-i-prefer-optionok-or-else-instead-of-optionok-or)).

## `if let`

This solution can still lead to a staircase of code if nested, but may be more appropriate if the `else` branch logic is more involved.

```
fn bar2(x: Option<u64>) -> Result<u64, MyErrors> {
    if let Some(x) = x {
        // Lot of stuff here as well.
        Ok(x * 2)
    } else {
        Err(MyErrors::SomeError)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice approach - just adapted it myself for the same 'problem'. Part of me wishes the `?` operator could actually be used for early return of `None` just like errors from `Result`, but it probably makes more sense (ie. return values are more 'meaningful') just to use result anyways

Comment: @kevlarr You can use `?` with `Option`s, it's mixing them with `Result`s which is a touch awkward. On nightly you can `impl From<NoneError> for MyError` and enable  `try_trait` feature, and it will work. Most error handling libraries, I'd imagine, also provide nice helpers for this - I'm mostly a `snafu` user, see `OptionExt` in its docs.

Comment: Wow... I didn't realize about ? with options... Sigh.. Thanks!

Comment: ? is not from the `Option`, it's from Result, but you transfor, from `Option` to `Result` when you call `.ok_or`

Answer (score 8):

Since Rust 1.65, you can use a [let-else statement](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html#let-else-statements):

```rust
fn bar3(x: Option<u64>) -> Result<u64, MyErrors> {
    let Some(x) = x else {
        return Err(MyErrors::SomeError);
    };
    Ok(x * 2)
}
```