# Is there a way to catch "division by zero" errors without checking in advance?

Tags: rust

How to catch zero division errors without checking in advance?

In python, It is able to with try..except.

```py
num1 = 3
num2 = 0
try:
    num1 / num2
    """
        I know that it should be check before divide but I want to do 
        without check in advance.
    """
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Divided by zero")
```

I understand that checking the divisor is better.
But I am looking for a way to without checking in advance in Rust.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The safest choice is to use one of the various [`checked_div`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.i32.html#method.checked_div) functions, which return an `Option<{number}>`.

```rust
fn do_calculation() -> Result<i32, &'static str> {
    let num1 = 2;
    let num2 = 0;
    num1.checked_div(num2)
        .ok_or_else(|| {
            // produce some error value, using &'static str merely to reduce boilerplate
            "division by zero"
        })
}
```

Then at the called site, one would have the equivalent of the catch clause:

```
do_calculation().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
    eprintln!("Oh no! {}", e);
});
```

These functions are still roughly equivalent to checking the divisor for 0 before performing the division proper.

See also:

- [Option types and early returns. return an Error when is_none()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55307746)
- [How do you define custom `Error` types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42584368)

Comment: `checked_div` is not implemented for float types `f32` and `f64`. This answer would be more complete if it also gave a solution for that.