# Implement std::option::NoneError for a custom Error enum

Tags: rust

I am using a custom error enum, and I want to unwrap optional variables and have the error working with the custom error enum. When I try adding ? to the end of the variable, I get the following error:

```
the trait `From<NoneError>` is not implemented for `EngineError`
```

This is a snippet of my code

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum EngineError {
    NotFound(String),
    Stack(String),
}
...
fn func() -> Result<(), EngineError> {
    let var = get_some_optional_value()?; // this can return NoneError
    Ok(())
}
```

I have tried implementing the error

```
impl From<std::option::NoneError> for EngineError{ 
    fn from(_: std::option::NoneError) -> Self { todo!() }
}
```

but that gives the error

```
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'try_trait'
```

One solution is adding `.ok_or(EngineError::NotFound("Some text".into()))?;`, but I would like one which does not require this

Comment: Just implement it : `impl From<NoneError> for EngineError{ // impl here}`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add that I have tried this, I will update the question

Comment: `std::option::NoneError` is unstable - meaning it's not yet part of the language. In that case you should use the `nightly` version of rust, but keep in mind that this `NoneError` may change incompatibly or even disappear from the language in a future version

Comment: Does this mean that I would need to do .or_or?

Comment: @rahokey531 Yes, but preferably `.ok_or_else` so that you don't allocate a string unless the value actually is `None`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Option types and early returns. return an Error when is\_none()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307746/option-types-and-early-returns-return-an-error-when-is-none)

Comment: No, not really, I wanted the ability to do it without ok_or[_else] and if, by implementing the error for my custom error, but thank you very much for the comments!

Comment: I'm curious: I can't find `std::option::NoneError` anywhere, and the playground [seems to agree it doesn't exist](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=672a011f3cd8e331f04d4d43a2b470e1), so you're probably using a (very, potentially) old Rust version. What's the output from `rustc -V`?