# In what situation `..._or()` is better than `..._or_else(|| {})` and why?

Tags: rust, lazy-evaluation, rust-clippy

If the variant `..._or_else()` is **executed only when it's needed**

```rs
// example
let value = option.unwrap_or_else(|| compute_value(argument));
// only executed if `option` is of enum variant Option::None
```

Then is there any situation that `..._or()` has any advantage?

I [understand that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547293/why-should-i-prefer-optionok-or-else-instead-of-optionok-or), if the result inside `..._or_else()` has already been calculated, then using `..._or()` can be used without drawback. But is there any advantage in this situation?

I have tried situation and found the clippy rule that suggest to change from `..._or_else()` to `..._or()` and I am having difficulty understanding the reason of [this rule](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#/unnecessary_lazy_evaluations):

> ### Why is this bad?
>
> Using eager evaluation is shorter and simpler in some cases.
>
> ### Known problems
>
> It is possible, but not recommended for Deref and Index to have side effects. Eagerly evaluating > them can change the semantics of the program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `*_or` instead of `*_or_else` when you already have the value saves at least 7 characters (`_else` and `||` possibly more  `{}`), so it's less noise.

It also results in creating one fewer closure—which might be unknown or unfamiliar syntax to a new Rustacean or developer of another programming language—whether that makes a measurable difference in performance or compile time I'm not sure but it is definitely less work for the compiler and for the people reading the code.

Comment: With optimization they compile to the exact same code, at least in a basic situation ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fv8TP4c1j)). In debug mode however, the `*_or` version is much shorter and almost certainly faster.